How to Prevent Swiper Slides from Moving After Dropping an Item with Sortable.js?
I'm working on a React project where I am integrating two libraries: Swiper and Sortable.js. Swiper is being used to create a carousel, and Sortable.js is enabling drag-and-drop functionality within the slides.
The issue I'm facing is that after I drop an item using Sortable.js, the Swiper slide starts moving along with the mouse pointer, as if it's being dragged. This behavior persists until I click somewhere else or interact with the Swiper in some way. This only happens when i drag and drop an item horizontally using sortable.
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import { Mousewheel, A11y, Navigation, Pagination } from "swiper/modules";
import Sortable from 'sortablejs';
import DraggableItem from "./DraggableItem.tsx";
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/mousewheel';
import './SweetSlider.css';

interface ISweetSlider {
  items: any[];
  rows: number;
  columns: number;
  showBullets?: boolean;
}

const SweetSlider: React.FC<ISweetSlider> = ({ items, rows, columns, showBullets }) => {
  const screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
  const [itemsPerPage, setItemsPerPage] = useState<number>(rows * columns);
  const [numberOfPages, setNumberOfPages] = useState<number>(Math.ceil(items.length / itemsPerPage));
  const [widthOfItem, setWidthOfItem] = useState<number>((screenWidth / columns) - (columns - 1) * 10);
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState<number>(0);
  const [sortedItems, setSortedItems] = useState(items);
  const [allowSwiping, setAllowSwiping] = useState(true)
  const sortableRefs = useRef<any[]>([]);
  const dragItem = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    setItemsPerPage(rows * columns);
    setNumberOfPages(Math.ceil(items.length / itemsPerPage));
    setWidthOfItem((screenWidth / columns) - (columns - 1) * 10);
  }, [items, rows, columns]);


  useEffect(() => {
    sortableRefs.current.forEach((sortableElement) => {
      Sortable.create(sortableElement, {
        group: 'sweetslider',
        animation: 90,
        delay: 500,
        ghostClass: 'custom-ghost',
        onChoose:(evt) => {
          setAllowSwiping(false)
          const draggedElement = evt.item;
          const rect = draggedElement.getBoundingClientRect();

          if (dragItem.current) {
            dragItem.current.textContent = draggedElement.textContent;
            dragItem.current.style.display = 'flex';
            dragItem.current.style.left = ${rect.left}px;
            dragItem.current.style.top = ${rect.top}px;
          }
        },
        onStart: (evt) => {
            evt.from.addEventListener('drag', (e) => {
              if (dragItem.current) {
                dragItem.current.style.left = ${e.pageX - widthOfItem / 2}px;
                dragItem.current.style.top = ${e.pageY - 50}px;
              }
            });
        },
        onEnd: (event: any) => {
          const newItemsOrder = [...sortedItems];
          const movedItem = newItemsOrder.splice(event.oldIndex, 1)[0];
          newItemsOrder.splice(event.newIndex, 0, movedItem);
          setSortedItems(newItemsOrder);
          if (dragItem.current) {
            dragItem.current.style.display = 'none';
          }
          setAllowSwiping(true)
        },
      });
    });
  }, [sortedItems]);


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(is swiping allowed: ${allowSwiping})
  }, [allowSwiping]);


  const pageRender = (itemsToRender: any[]) => {
    const slides: any[] = [];

    for (let counter = 0; counter < numberOfPages; counter++) {
      const firstItemIndex: number = counter * itemsPerPage;
      const lastItemIndex: number = (counter + 1) * itemsPerPage;
      const pageItems: any[] = itemsToRender.slice(firstItemIndex, lastItemIndex);

      slides.push(
        <SwiperSlide key={counter}>
          <div ref={(el) => (sortableRefs.current[counter] = el)}>
            {pageItems.map((pageItem) => (
              <DraggableItem
                key={pageItem}
                style={{
                  width: widthOfItem
                }}
                text={pageItem}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
      );
    }
    return slides;
  };


  const bulletRender = () => {
    const bullets = [];

    for (let counter = 0; counter < numberOfPages; counter++) {
      bullets.push(
        <div
          key={bullet-${counter}}
          className={bullet ${counter === activeIndex ? 'active' : ''}}
        ></div>
      );
    }

    return bullets;
  };

  return (
      <>
        <div className="sweetslider-wrapper">
          <Swiper
              modules={[Mousewheel, A11y, Navigation, Pagination]}
              mousewheel
              slidesPerView={1}
              threshold={20}
              onSlideChange={(swiper) => setActiveIndex(swiper.activeIndex)}
              touchStartPreventDefault={false}
              allowSlideNext={allowSwiping}
              allowSlidePrev={allowSwiping}
          >
            {pageRender(sortedItems)}
          </Swiper>

          {showBullets && (
              <div className="bullets-wrapper">
                {bulletRender()}
              </div>
          )}
        </div>
        <div ref={dragItem} id="dragItem" style={{position: "absolute", width: widthOfItem, display: "none"}}></div>

      </>
  );
};

export default SweetSlider;

I tried stopPropagation: true and also some other props of swiper
I tried evt.stopPropagation() in sortable hooks
